# push notification not working in play store but it work for development

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my App the push notification is working fine for development but its not working in **play store**.

Do I need to create any certificate like **IOS**?

Comment: I'm not an expert in GCM, but do you use a different applicationId and/or a different certificate for signing your application, if you publish it on google play? I think you have to register your application with correct signed sha1-key at google developer console. Also check, if the needed permission fits to your application id.

Comment: No, GCM doesn't work like IOS Provision Profiles or certificates. You need to open GCM functionality in https://developers.google.com/ and put you signing key or hash for API key

Comment: see my answer for proper steps to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Register for GCM for Production APPS

- Step 1: Log into https://cloud.google.com/console with your Google
  account
- Step 2: In the navigation on the left, go into "APIs & auth > APIs"
- Step 3: Find "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" and click the "OFF"
  button next to it (note: this might involve then agreeing to
  additional terms of service)
- Step 4: In the navigation on the left, go into "APIs & auth >
  Registered apps"
- Step 5: Wait a really long time, apparently.
- Step 6: Click the red REGISTER APP button.
- Step 7: Give the app a name and choose Web Application, then click
  Register
- Step 8: Click the "Server Key" section for your server key

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember there's a place where you provide the package-name and the SHA1-fingerprint of the keystore used to sign your APK.

There you should provide one line with the package-name and the fingerprint of your debug-keystore and another line with the package-name and the production-keystore (used to sign the app for playstore).